# Prevent yarn from deleting node_modules when passing in different modules_folder

Tags: yarnpkg

For my front end project's infrastructure, using yarn JavaScript package manager version 1.1.0 I want to do the following:

- Install all dependencies to default directory `node_modules` (Actually installing `devDependencies` would be sufficient here. However, as far as I see, this feature is requested but not yet implemented) doing simply `yarn install --ignore-engines`
- Install all front end dependencies (= not `devDependencies`) to `src/plugins` doing `yarn install --modules-folder ./src/plugins --production --ignore-engines`

Problem is: The latter command will delete the content of `node_modules`. Obviously yarn is assuming that doing an installation into a different folder means that the previous target directory is not needed anymore. However, that's not the case for me: I want the "normal" dependencies in `src/plugins` while keeping the `devDependencies` in `node_modules`.

Comment: What does your Gruntfile look like? Without the files, it seems very hard for us to replicate this error and see what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to look closer to my Gruntfile. Was able to narrow down the problem and rework the question

Comment: Have you tried running the commands in the reverse order? First run it with the `--modules-folder` flag, then `yarn install --ignore-engines`?

Comment: No. But even if that showed a different behavior, it would not help and solve my problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution: Doing it with two different `package.json` files at different locations. Like this:

```
cp package.json src
cd src
yarn install --modules-folder ./plugins --production --ignore-engines
rm package.json
```